# How to find original variables in merMod objects with interaction terms (fitted with lme4 package)?

Tags: r, interaction, lme4

I would like to calculate interaction effects, like shown in [this blog posting](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpreting-interactions-in-regression/), so I can calculate `y = (b0 + (b1 * xa) + (b3 * xa * xb))`, where `b0` is the estimate of the intercept, `b1` is the estimate of the predictor A and `b3` is the estimate of the interaction between predictor A and B.

**To do this, I need**

1. the estimates from the fitted model
2. the original values of the predictors (i.e. the "data.frame" from the used variables, where each value is inserted into the formula shown above)

**For "simple" generalized linear models**, I can use the data matrix parameter to store the original data values in the fitted model object (`glm(... x=TRUE)`. Example:

```
fit <- glm(f1care ~ c12hour + neg_c_7 + c172 + 
           sex1 + sex2 + c172:neg_c_7 + sex1:c12hour,
           data = mydf,
           x = TRUE,
           family = binomial("logit"))

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    1.4674300  0.1759883   8.338  < 2e-16 ***
c12hour        0.0016157  0.0016315   0.990   0.3220    
neg_c_7       -0.0549614  0.0108868  -5.048 4.45e-07 ***
c1721         -0.1575547  0.2752344  -0.572   0.5670    
sex12         -0.0320619  0.1286984  -0.249   0.8033    
sex22          0.2091354  0.0874629   2.391   0.0168 *  
neg_c_7:c1721  0.0090043  0.0202720   0.444   0.6569    
c12hour:sex12 -0.0003121  0.0018246  -0.171   0.8642  

> head(fit$x)
  (Intercept) c12hour neg_c_7 c1721 sex12 sex22 neg_c_7:c1721 c12hour:sex12
1           1      10       9     0     1     1             0            10
2           1       4      13     1     1     1            13             4
3           1      12      21     0     1     1             0            12
4           1      60      14     0     1     1             0            60
5           1      40      17     0     1     1             0            40
6           1      50      17     0     1     1             0            50
```

As you can see, the coefficients' names are the same as the column names in the model data frame (`fit$x`).

If I find an interaction term (e.g. `c12hour:sex12`), I can split the name at the colon, have `c12hour` and `sex12`, and find the values via the model matrix column names (names are identical).

**Now my question is, how to do this with `merMod` objects?** The column names of the data frame used to fit the model (`fit@frame`) with original values looks like this:

```
library(lme4)
fit <- glmer(f1care ~ c12hour + neg_c_7 + c172 + 
             sex1 + sex2 + 
             c172:neg_c_7 + sex1:c12hour + (1|g2ctry),
             data = mydf,
             family = binomial("logit"))

> colnames(fit@frame)[-1]
[1] "c12hour" "neg_c_7" "c172"    "sex1"    "sex2"    "g2ctry"
```

The coeffciients, accessed via `summary` or `fixef`, look like this:

```
Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    1.2388127  0.2382648   5.199    2e-07 ***
c12hour        0.0018070  0.0016450   1.098 0.272018    
neg_c_7       -0.0387817  0.0115511  -3.357 0.000787 ***
c1721          0.1187357  0.2842743   0.418 0.676181    
sex12         -0.0305578  0.1306499  -0.234 0.815069    
sex22          0.1580400  0.0897806   1.760 0.078358 .  
neg_c_7:c1721 -0.0106958  0.0209961  -0.509 0.610458    
c12hour:sex12 -0.0009486  0.0018350  -0.517 0.605206   

> cbind(fixef(fit))
                       [,1]
(Intercept)    1.2388126568
c12hour        0.0018069626
neg_c_7       -0.0387817065
c1721          0.1187357405
sex12         -0.0305578499
sex22          0.1580400407
neg_c_7:c1721 -0.0106958049
c12hour:sex12 -0.0009485618
```

As you can see, the column names `sex1` and `sex2` are not idenctical to the coefficients "names" `sex12` and `sex22` (unlike in the first, simple `glm` example, where both are identical).

My current approach is

- to take the column name (e.g. `sex1`)
- check if it is a `factor`, and if so, retrieve `levels` (e.g. `1` and `2`)
- concat column name and factor level (so we have `sex11` and `sex12`)
- find the interaction term, which includes the concatenated "predictor name" (so `sex11` will give no match, however, `sex12` will match the second interaction term `c12hour:sex12`)

I wonder if this is the best or only solution, or if there might be cases where my way of "detecting" interaction terms won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, `model.matrix` does the trick and returns a data frame where column names correspond to the term names in the model summary.